# awk match pattern if character not present on line

Tags: awk

I am trying to find a way to match a pattern in a file only if on the line with the pattern a certain character is not present. If it is present then the line with the pattern should be ignored.

The two types of lines are like this:

```
.
.
.
     total energy              =   -7693.64180923 Ry
     Harris-Foulkes estimate   =   -7693.64180923 Ry
     estimated scf accuracy    <       0.00000016 Ry
.
.
.
.
!    total energy              =   -7693.64023456 Ry
     Harris-Foulkes estimate   =   -7693.64023461 Ry
     estimated scf accuracy    <       0.00000010 Ry
.
.
.
     total energy              =   -7693.64180921 Ry
     Harris-Foulkes estimate   =   -7693.64180923 Ry
     estimated scf accuracy    <       0.00000016 Ry
.
.
.
!    total energy              =   -7693.64023459 Ry
     Harris-Foulkes estimate   =   -7693.64023461 Ry
     estimated scf accuracy    <       0.00000010 Ry
```

Is there a way to do this?
If I match patters then all the lines with the patters appear. If I match the `!` character then I extract the lines I do not want to appear.

Thank you

Edit: In order to make it more clear. The file I have has a lot of data. Some of the lines contain `pattern`. If I do

```
awk '/total energy/' file.dat
```

I get:

```
     total energy              =   -7693.64180923 Ry
!    total energy              =   -7693.64023456 Ry
     total energy              =   -7693.64180921 Ry
!    total energy              =   -7693.64023459 Ry
```

etc. As you can see I get all the lines that contain `total energy` and among those there are lines that also contain the `!` character at the beginning.

My goal is to select only the lines the contain `total energy` but do not contain the `!` character. So the command I imagine is like this but obviously is not the correct syntax:

```
awk '/if line contains has "total energy" and "!" then keep going else print line that has "total energy" and not "!"/' file.dat
```

file.dat does not contain only lines with `total energy` and lines with `total energy` and `!`. There is more data in there so printing all the lines that do not contain `!` line the answer below will give me the entire file without the lines that contain `!`.

I hope this is clearer.

Final Edit:

using @Ed's answer I was able to solve my problem. I was after selecting the numerical data on the lines starting with `total energy` but exclude the data from the lines starting with `!`. The final goal was to also extract the data from two lines below the `total energy` pattern (the lines starting with `estimated scf accuracy`). The command I came up with following @Ed comment is this:

```
awk '/     total energy/ && !/!/{a=$4; nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr{print a,"   ",$5}' file.dat
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Replace the word `pattern` with the word `string` or the word `regexp` throughout the text and sample code in your question to clarify what you're trying to do.  In your sample input/output replace `pattern` with a truly representative string that you want to find. The word `pattern` is highly ambiguous and best avoided. In addition to doing that to clarify if you're using string or regexp matching, also tell us (again, in your question) if you're looking for whole word or partial word matches or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might want:

```
awk '/pattern/ && !/!/' file
```

but see [my comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850165/awk-match-pattern-if-character-not-present-on-line/60855501#comment107669369_60850165) as it's not clear at this point exactly what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: I have edited the question to include the relevant sample from my data. The pattern I was talking about is the string `total energy`. The end goal is to select those lines with `total energy` and then extract the numbers at the end. I know how to do the last part but I don't know how to select only those lines.

Comment: I was able to use your answer to solve my problem! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `!` to negate the pattern.

`awk '!/\!/{if ($0 ~ "pattern") print}'`

Demo:

```
$echo -e '123!abc\n123#abc\n123def' 
123!abc
123#abc
123def
$echo -e '123!abc\n123#abc\n123def'  | awk '/\!/{print}' # print line with !
123!abc
$echo -e '123!abc\n123#abc\n123def'  | awk '!/\!/{print}' # print line not with !
123#abc
123def
$
```

Comment: this prints all the line that do not contain character `!` but this isn't what I need. Maybe I wasn't clear with the question. I will edit it now!